# Replacing row elements with top and bottom elements

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

unsorted data:

```
id  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10
M1  SM1 137 137 +   SM1 168 255 +   xxl 31
M2  SM1 3026005 3026005 -   SM1 3025051 3026062 +   xmu 0
M3  SM1 308128  308128  -   SM1 306713  308597  -   ucl 0
M4  SM1 3027792 3027792 -   SM1 3026280 3028359 +   oml 0
M5  SM1 308129  308129  -   SM1 306713  308597  -   uul 0
M6  SM1 3029695 3029695 -   SM1 3028946 3029864 +   oma 0
M7  SM1 3029738 3029738 -   SM1 3028946 3029864 +   oma 0
M8  SM1 3030415 3030415 +   SM1 3029860 3030682 +   omu 0
M9  SM1 3057386 3057386 -   SM1 3056910 3057822 -   ucle    0
M10 SM1 3069715 3069715 +   SM1 3069459 3069567 +   ohm 148
M11 SM1 3097751 3097751 -   SM1 3096951 3097860 -   umn 0
M12 SM1 3098025 3098025 +   SM1 3098110 3099157 +   icy 85
M14 SM1 3099816 3099816 -   SM1 3100255 3100552 -   occl    439
M15 SMP 3100015 3100015 -   SMP 3100255 3100552 -   occl    240
M16 SMP 3103300 3103300 +   SMP 3104483 3106040 +   abl 183
M17 SMP 3116858 3116858 -   SMP 3115395 3116193 -   zyc 665
M18 SMP 3121053 3121053 -   SMP 3120207 3121845 -   umq 0
M19 SMP 3121957 3121957 +   SMP 3120207 3121845 -   umq 112
```

Data sorted in the following order: data$V8, data$V7, data$V1 so as to enable effective analysis.

sorted data:

```
id  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10
M3  SM1 308128  308128  -   SM1 306713  308597  -   ucl 0
M5  SM1 308129  308129  -   SM1 306713  308597  -   uul 0
M9  SM1 3057386 3057386 -   SM1 3056910 3057822 -   ucle    0
M11 SM1 3097751 3097751 -   SM1 3096951 3097860 -   umn 0
M14 SM1 3099816 3099816 -   SM1 3100255 3100552 -   occl    439
M15 SMP 3100015 3100015 -   SMP 3100255 3100552 -   occl    240
M17 SMP 3116858 3116858 -   SMP 3115395 3116193 -   zyc 665
M18 SMP 3121053 3121053 -   SMP 3120207 3121845 -   umq 0
M19 SMP 3121957 3121957 +   SMP 3120207 3121845 -   umq 112
M1  SM1 137 137 +   SM1 168 255 +   xxl 31
M2  SM1 3026005 3026005 -   SM1 3025051 3026062 +   xmu 0
M4  SM1 3027792 3027792 -   SM1 3026280 3028359 +   oml 0
M6  SM1 3029695 3029695 -   SM1 3028946 3029864 +   oma 0
M7  SM1 3029738 3029738 -   SM1 3028946 3029864 +   oma 0
M8  SM1 3030415 3030415 +   SM1 3029860 3030682 +   omu 0
M10 SM1 3069715 3069715 +   SM1 3069459 3069567 +   ohm 148
M12 SM1 3098025 3098025 +   SM1 3098110 3099157 +   icy 85
M16 SMP 3103300 3103300 +   SMP 3104483 3106040 +   abl 183
```

My aim is to carry out the following on the sorted data:

1. if data$V10 > 0 & data$V1 == data$V5 & data$V4 == data$V8, then
2. Replace the content of row at column V9 with "Beween_TopRowElement-BottomRowElement"
   (if TopRowElement and BottomRowElement are different from the element in the row at column v9)

Example "occl" with id M15 and located in col V9 is greater than 0, hence it will be replaced by "Between_umn_zyc", 
since the TopRowElement is the same name as occl, so the next top element is used.

I also need to take care of when there is no row above or below a particular element.

My attempt at writing the R code is as follow:

```
data <- read.delim("data.dat", header=TRUE)
data <- data[order(data$V8, data$V7, data$V1)]
for (i in data.sorted){
  if (data$V10 > 0 & data$V1 == data$V5 & data$V4 == data$V8){
      if (i!=i-1 |  i!=i+1){
        data$V9 =  data["Between_",i-1,"_", i+1]
        data$V1 == data$V5
      }
  }

}
write.table(data, "results.xls", "sep=\t")
```

Expected output for M15:

```
M15 SMP 3100015 3100015 -   SMP 3100255 3100552 -   Between_umn_zyc 240
```

Can someone please help improve my poor attempt. Thanks

Comment: What is all this `Beween_TopRowElement`, `BottomRowElement`,`TopRowElement`, `BottomRowElement`, `Between_umn_zyc` stuff?

Comment: For clarification:

Between_umn_zyc means:
Between is a descriptive string. umn is a name of an element.zyc - is a name of an element. So, Between_umn_zyc describes the fact that M15 is between umn and zyc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've missed a comma in your sorting :

```
data <- data[order(data$V8, data$V7, data$V1) , ]
```

If I'm understanding your question, you need to find for each element of V9 the immediately preceeding *different* value of V9.  This should give you that value:

```
V9 <- data$V9
sameAsPredecessor <- V9[-length(V9)] == V9[-1]
indexOfDifferent <- cumsum(!sameAsPredecessor)
predecessor <- V9[c(NA, indexOfDifferent)]
```

Where I'm adding a `NA` at the beginning, as a way of dealing with the edge-case

You can get the bound in the other direction similarly:

```
V9 <- rev(data$V9)
sameAsPredecessor <- V9[-length(V9)] == V9[-1]
indexOfDifferent <- cumsum(!sameAsPredecessor)
follower <- rev(V9[c(NA, indexOfDifferent)])
```

So you now have two vectors `predecessor` and `follower`, which you can insert into the relevant rows - something along the lines of:

```
ind <- data$V10 > 0 & data$V1 == data$V5 & data$V4 == data$V8
data$V9[ind] <- sprintf("Between_%s_%s", predecessor[ind], follower[ind])
```

And you shouldn't need any loops

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin for the code. Unfortunately, NAs were generated in the final output: 

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ind, value = c(472L, 472L, 472L, 472L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: It's _Gavin_ not _Kevin_.  If you change the type of data$V9 to character by `data$V9 <- as.character(dat$V9)` then you won't be restricted to solely the values that were in that column originally.

Comment: Apologies about your name Gavin. Pleased to let you know that that fixed the NAN problem. Provided these are satisfied:data$V10 > 0 & data$V1 == data$V5 & data$V4 == data$V8, then are a couple of scenarios.
(1). In any situation where the immediate bounding value (above and below) is different from V9 value, this applies: "Between_above_below", 
(2). Otherwise if immediate bounding value (above and below) is the same as V9 value, then the code looks for the next bounding value up/down that are different from V9, and finally applies "Between_above_below"

Comment: Addition to above comment: Unfortunately, the "Between_Top_Bottom" are not correct in the output. I'm sure it's due to my poor explanation in the first place, hence I added the above comment. Thanks

Comment: OK, use `indexOfReplacement <- match(V9, V9)-1` as this will find, for each row, the rownumber of the preceding different V9 even if it's not its immediate neighbour.  Assuming your values of V9 come in runs that don't actually repeat.  You need to be specific about exactly what you're trying to achieve - we're doing a lot of guess-work so if this doesn't answer you're question, try and extract out exactly what's required of V9 - we don't really need to consider the conditionals on other columns.

Comment: Still not there yet. Perhaps my algorithm is been wrong all along too. As in the example of M15 in the first post, the idea was to consider "240" as a sign that values of either columns V2/V3 (3100015) is outside the range [v8(3100255)-V9 (3100552)], and if data$V10 > 0 & data$V1 == data$V5 & data$V4 == data$V8, then put V9 element in a range that it might be. In this case, occl(row M15, col V9) will be within interval between the ranges for umn and zyc. I welcome a different algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation is still not making much sense.  I think there are two parts - finding which rows you want changing, and then what values you're going to insert.

Comment: (Sorry - edit took longer than allowed by SO)  You don't say which part isn't working.  If on the sorted data, `c(NA,V9[match(V9[-1], V9)-1])` isn't giving a vector of possible lower-bound replacement values let me know.  If it is, you really need to be more careful in explaining the row-selection criteria.

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioned what is still wrong. After a long check of the results, I found that indexOfReplacement <- match(V9, V9) for upper bound and indexOfReplacement <- match(V9[-1], V9)-1 and lower bound works fine in most of the scenarios. The only problem left is when there is long run of repetitive (similar) values above V9 element, then the replacement value are wrong in this instance.

Comment: For the other bound, you're probably best off with `2 + length(V9) -match(V9, rev(V9))` - _match_ finds the first match, so we reverse the vector to find the last match, then subtract that from 1+number of rows to get index of last match in the original sequence, then add 1 to get the row _after_ that, which is the expression I've given.

Comment: If that answers the question, could you accept the answer please

Comment: Many thanks for your help Gavin. Really appreciate it!